When executing the stored procedure for productID P1, it incorrectly calculates 0 items sold for 2020, individual query showing 35 items sold in 2020
I made a stored procedure  that outputs the total number of items sold during the last three years for the P1 Product ID. Input the ProductID when invoking the procedure.**
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE evaluateProduct(
    IN input_productid VARCHAR(10),
    OUT total_sold_2020 INT,
    OUT total_sold_2021 INT,
    OUT total_sold_2022 INT,
    OUT total_sold_overall INT
)
BEGIN
    -- Calculate totals for each year and overall total
    SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(date) = 2020 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(date) = 2021 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(date) = 2022 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(quantity)
    INTO total_sold_2020, total_sold_2021, total_sold_2022, total_sold_overall
    FROM orders
    WHERE productID = input_productid
    AND date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), interval 3 year);
END //

DELIMITER ;


call  evaluateProduct('p1', @total_sold_2020, @total_sold_2021, @total_sold_2022, @total_sold_overall);
**select @total_sold_2020, @total_sold_2021, @total_sold_2022, @total_sold_overall;

when i run this i got 0 for @total_sold_2020 and when i individually calculates
select sum(quantity)
from orders
where productid='p1' and year(date)=2020;

i got answer 35 which is correct
[enter image description here]enter image description here(https://i.sstatic.net/BNQ0cozu.png)Iz.png)
i want to expect correct answe 35 for year 2020 when i run stored procedure

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Most likely you get no results due to your date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), interval 3 year) condition.

The result is correct, because you only look at a certain date range inside the procedure.
AND date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), interval 3 year) is AND date >= DATE '2021-07-03' today (on 2024-07-03).
There are zero rows for year 2020 since then.
